# How can I allow users to change their Liferay portrait from a velocity template?

Tags: liferay

I´m coding a template for a customize theme and would like to let users change their Liferay portrait from there. In addition, it would be nice to add the functionality provided in the "official" window that gives the possibility to select a part of the uploaded image.

The simplest way I can imagine to do this is "building" a link that directly brings the user to that window without having to pass through his profile. Right now, I´m trying to do this with the JS function "Liferay.Portlet.openWindow" but still I haven't been able to find the correct arguments (including the large URL) to accomplish it.

Is what I´m trying to do possible? if so, could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution to that would be to build a custom liferay MVC or Vaadin protlet to do just that.

This is because the friendlyURL (large URL as you called it) to take a user to that place is usually generated on the fly within the portal instance so you may not have the correct redirection.

Also you would have to use the method `ImageLocalServiceUtil` which is used to upload images to do the actually portrait change.